# Problems with Excel 2010 "Find" function returning #value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to use the Find function to determine the presence or absence of a substring in a text cell.  When I use =FIND("string",B21)>0, I get TRUE if the string is found and a #value error if not.  In this example, cell B21 is a text cell.  Excel's help is useless in this case.  Can someone clue me in about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Excel's help is useless in this case" - I don't think so. It clearly states that return value is error when sought string couldn't be found.

Use
`=IFERROR(FIND(...)>0,FALSE)`

Comment: How come the formula returns `#Value` instead of `FALSE`?  I guess because the equation isn't really a TRUE/FALSE result?

Comment: The problem is getting an error instead of FALSE.  Why this is the case is not stated in the help, so my comment about the help being useless in this case still stands, IMHO.

Comment: When I try to add FALSE as a second argument in the ISERROR call, I get an error message indicating too many arguments for the function.

Comment: @GregorJ: IFERROR is different from ISERROR and behaves differently from IF.  With IF, you specify values for both true and false results.  IFERROR returns the result of the first argument unless there's an error, in which case it returns the second.  ISERROR simply checks for whether the result is an error and returns true or false.

Comment: @GregorJ: Your `FIND` results in error, `#value>0` is still an error, this is how Excel works.

Comment: @Kerbal: See my answer to Gregor

Comment: IFERROR is exactly what I needed.  I get that #value is not a number or a boolean value and needs to be caught by something that can trap the error and return the bool that I need.  Thanks for the help.