# Speed difference between ISNUMBER() and COUNT() when searching for substrings within text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to see which Excel formula is preferable - `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,"myText"))=TRUE, doSomething)` or `IF(COUNT(SEARCH(A1,"myText"))=1, doSomething)`.

Is there any sizable speed difference between the two?

Comment: I'm not sure if such performance specs are published, but this is the kind of thing you could easily test yourself.

Comment: With this formula I don't expect measurable difference, however, looking for your formula: 1. For future readers `ISNUMBER` is more clear, `COUNT` can create confusion. 2. Where your expected output is 1 / FALSE you'll get error, have a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/1034331/problems-with-excel-2010-find-function-returning-value/1034332?noredirect=1#comment1443471_1034332

Comment: @MátéJuhász Can you clarify what you mean by "COUNT can create confusion"?

Comment: looking to a `COUNT()` function at first people think you want to actually get the number / quantity of something, using it for data conversion isn't its original purpose.

Comment: Why not just `=COUNTIF(A:A,"myText")`?

Comment: Sorry about the unclear post title. It has been fixed.

Comment: @MátéJuhász - I will also test the ISERROR() approach as well using the calculation timer mentioned in the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel MVP [Charles Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88173/charles-williams) has a calculation timer [here](http://decisionmodels.com/downloads.htm#RngCalc)

Apply it to a sizable range, not just one cell, and see what it tells you.

Comment: Awesome. This is just what I'm after. Thanks for the link.

Comment: If you want to meet Charles Williams and learn about optimising spreadsheet performance, hear about lots more interesting Excel topics presented by lots more Excel MVPs and the Microsoft Excel developers, consider attending the [Excel Summit South](https://excelsummitsouth.wordpress.com/) conference in Auckland. There are also sessions in Sydney and Melbourne, but why go there if you can have it in NZ?

Comment: Haha - I'm originally from Akl, living now in Boston. Would be a cool summit, but two trips back home in 2 months is pushing it. Thanks for the tip though. Answer has been marked as solved with actual results listed below.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Calculation Results]

It turns out that the two formula are the same. However, as you can see, using IFERROR() is just a wee bit faster.

Tested on 500,000 rows, i7 core SSD machine, running x64 2013 version of Excel on x64 Windows 8.1